# The history of Haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, topological-groups, haar-measure

Haar measure is a well-known concept in measure theory.

Many books are perfectly dedicated to present its existence and uniqueness such as measure theory for D. Cohn.

I am looking for a good reference on the history of Haar measure.

Comment: You will likely get a better answer [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Now crossposted [there](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/9851/on-the-history-of-haar-measure) as suggested.